# PHP Stripe retrieve paymentintent (connect)

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I'm attempting to retrieve a paymentintent so i can validate that it's successful, when retrieving i always get a "no such payment intent" error.

Some relevant PHP code;

```
//setting api key
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_xxxxx'); 

//creating payment intent on pageload
$intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
            'amount' => 1099,
            'currency' => 'USD',
            'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
            'application_fee_amount' => '500',
           ], [
            'stripe_account' => 'acct_xxxx'
        ]);

//now on redirect(after coming back from 3DS with a $_GET that contains a intent id i'm retrieving paymentintent and confirming payment status.
$intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::retrieve($_GET['intentID'], array("stripe_account" => 'acct_xxxx'));
```

Relevant JS code on page

```
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_xxxxx', {
   stripeAccount: 'acct_xxxx'
});
            stripe.handleCardPayment(clientSecret, {
              payment_method_data: {
                billing_details: {
                  name: cardHolder.value
                },
                card: {
                  "token": tokenResult["token"]["id"]
                }
              }
            }).
//and more code which processes the redirect for 3ds.
```

var_dumping $intent will show that my error looks like this;

```
"error": {
    "code": "resource_missing",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing",
    "message": "No such payment_intent: 'pi_xxxxx'",
    "param": "intent",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
}
```

Comment: You likely have a mismatch in account IDs. I'd start by making sure that the account ID you pass in when creating the PaymentIntent matches the one you pass in when retrieving the PaymentIntent.

Comment: The payment session is better in all ways. You should give it a try.
Customers trust more than filling card details on untrusted sites.